# Modal Popup is showing extra space and vertical scrollbar sometimes

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have created 6 dynamic `Bootstrap` tables inside `Modal` Popup in `ReactJS`. The number of table that will show inside Modal depends completely on the dynamic data. There is one weird situation that is reproducing intermittently, sometimes the Modal popup is showing extra white space and vertical scroll bar unnecessarily. If I am refreshing the window, then it's working fine.

```
    let subModalDialogStyles = {
            base: {
              bottom: -250,
              transition: 'bottom 0.4s',
              width: '70%'
            },
            open: {
              bottom: 0
            }
      };

          <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} onRequestHide={this.hideModal} dialogStyles={subModalDialogStyles}>
              <ModalHeader>
              <h1 className="textAlign title-modal" >Problems in model {stmt}</h1>
              </ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
              <div className="form-horizontal">
              <div className="form-group">
              <div className="col-md-12 scroll" style={{maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 210px)" , overflowY: "auto"}}>
                {this.state.attrArray.length !=0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Attributes</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorAttr}}
                data={this.state.attrArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={attrCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                {this.state.restArray.length != 0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Restrictions</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorRes}}
                data={this.state.restArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={resCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                {this.state.crArray.length != 0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Coverage Requirements</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorCr}}
                data={this.state.crArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={crCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                {this.state.negCombArray.length != 0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Negative Combinations</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorNegComb}}
                data={this.state.negCombArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={negCombCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                {this.state.triggersArray.length != 0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Test Description Triggers</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorTriggers}}
                data={this.state.triggersArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={triggersCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                {this.state.idArray.length != 0 ? <h4 style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>Problems in Model Identification</h4> : ""}
                <BootstrapTable style={{color: this.state.colorId}}
                data={this.state.idArray}
                headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                columns={idCol}>
                </BootstrapTable>
                </div></div></div>
              </ModalBody>
              <ModalFooter>
                <button className="image-button" onClick={this.hideModal}>
                <img className="icons-small" src={require("../../images/cancel-icon.png")} />
                  Close
                </button>
              </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
```

Sometimes if I am opening `Inspect Element` before opening the modal popup, extra white space is coming in between the tables..and sometimes after the last table. Closing the inspect element and refreshing the screen will solve the issue...

Can someone please guide me why this is happening, and how can I escape from this situation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: @Andus, code added in description.

Comment: There are two possibilities there, one in `dialogStyles` prop passed to the `Modal` component itself, and the other one is the way you are styling your tables component container `div.scroll`, maxHeight can possibly produce this bug. can you play around those and let me know?